# Get value between brackets

Tags: ruby

I have:

```
item = "[a,b,c,d]"
```

I want the value between `[]`:

```
"a,b,c,d"
```

I tried:

```
item.split(/,/)
```

but this does not work. I tried `split`/`each` but neither works.

Comment: `item.scan(/(?<=\[).*(?=\])/)[0]`

Comment: @kiddorails `item[/(?<=\A\[).*(?=\]\z)/]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> item.delete('[|]')
#=> "a,b,c,d"
```

To override self value you can use **`delete!`**

**Note:** It only delete brackets from your string, if your value can be anything and you want to fetch only string within brackets then use:

```
> item = "hi [a,b,c,d] world"
> item[/(?<=\[).*(?=\])/]
# OR
> item[/\[(.*)\]/, 1]
#=> "a,b,c,d"
```

Answer (score 4):

extremely dirty but it should work for you:

```
item[1..-2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
item[/\[(.*?)\]/, 1]
```

Or:

```
item[/(?<=\[).*?(?=\])/]
```

Comment: The last one is a way to go (well, I’d add `\A` and `\z` anchors as well.)